# Does Three.js render lines in Collada files?

Tags: webgl, three.js, collada

I was working on a [Collada file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44791710/S_line.dae) which contains one line with material.

I cannot render this file in Three.js

I am not sure that Three.JS can render lines from Collada files.

What is the problem with this file? It works perfectly in SketchUp but I cannot load it in Three.js. Blender does not support lines and I could not check it there.

Answer (score 0):

try the canvas renderer? It has a 'rederLine()' method, the others do not. (line width etc are attributes of the material, btw -- not the line itself)

alternatively, query the contents of the threejs scene and make sure the line is really part of it

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.ColladaLoader` was replaced in 2017 with a new implementation. The current loader does support `lines` and `linestrips` definitions.